# How to get the current year only?

Tags: mysql

I have this query and I just want to get the current year only,

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(in_time,'%M %Y') as MonthlyAtt,
     count(employees_id) as AttCount,
     count(Distinct employees_id) as DistinctedAttCount

FROM attendance
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(in_time,'%M %Y') 
ORDER BY (in_time)
```

Sample Output

[Output of the Query Above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6j7h.png)

I just only want to show the Year 2019 only. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand it correct, you could try the below:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(in_time,'%M %Y') as MonthlyAtt,
     count(employees_id) as AttCount,
     count(Distinct employees_id) as DistinctedAttCount

FROM attendance 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(in_time,'%Y')=2019
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(in_time,'%M %Y') 
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(in_time,'%M %Y') desc
```

Use where clause to limit the search to only 2019

Comment: I mean i want to get the current Year in the output it should be 
January 2019, 
February 2019, 
March 2019, 
July 2019.

Comment: Then just add in a where clause to limit the 2019

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(in_time,'%M %Y') as MonthlyAtt,
     count(employees_id) as AttCount,
     count(Distinct employees_id) as DistinctedAttCount
FROM attendance
WHERE YEAR(in_time) = YEAR(CURDATE())
ORDER BY (in_time)
```